# Get session info failed

Tags: java, android, opentok

I'm trying to run the opentok android beta but I keep getting

```
07-28 19:46:03.703: W/opentok-session(1707): get session info failed
07-28 19:46:03.703: W/opentok-session(1707): com.opentok.webservices.TokenAuthRequest$TokenAuthRequestException: Error in response: Invalid Token: Sentinel missing
07-28 19:46:03.703: W/opentok-session(1707):    at com.opentok.webservices.TokenAuthRequest.issue(TokenAuthRequest.java:99)
07-28 19:46:03.703: W/opentok-session(1707):    at com.opentok.webservices.SessionInfo.<init>(SessionInfo.java:45)
07-28 19:46:03.703: W/opentok-session(1707):    at com.opentok.webservices.SessionInfo.fetch(SessionInfo.java:31)
07-28 19:46:03.703: W/opentok-session(1707):    at com.opentok.impl.SessionImpl.attach(SessionImpl.java:99)
07-28 19:46:03.703: W/opentok-session(1707):    at com.opentok.impl.SessionImpl.access$000(SessionImpl.java:55)
07-28 19:46:03.703: W/opentok-session(1707):    at com.opentok.impl.SessionImpl$1.run(SessionImpl.java:86)
07-28 19:46:03.703: W/opentok-session(1707):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
07-28 19:46:03.703: W/opentok-session(1707):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
07-28 19:46:03.703: W/opentok-session(1707):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-28 19:46:03.834: E/demo-hello-world(1707): session failed! com.opentok.android.OpentokException: Authorization Failure - Invalid credentials were provided.
```

I know it means that the session id and the token I'm providing is wrong but I don't know who that can be because I'm getting it from the opentok dashboard.

EDIT
This is the session id I used 1_MX4zNjA3NDkwMn4xMjcuMC4wLjF-TW9uIEp1bCAyOSAwNDoxNjozMiBQRFQgMjAxM34wLjIzMTkwMzMxfg

and the token I used

cGFydG5lcl9pZD0zNjA3NDkwMiZzZGtfdmVyc2lvbj10YnJ1YnktdGJyYi12MC45MS4yMDExLTAyLTE3JnNpZz0wMzY4NzQzYjFiNDgzNDI3NDAzZWU0ZWM0Yzg1OGVlZGI5YjI0ZGQ1OnJvbGU9cHVibGlzaGVyJnNlc3Npb25faWQ9MV9NWDR6TmpBM05Ea3dNbjR4TWpjdU1DNHdMakYtVFc5dUlFcDFiQ0F5T1NBd05Eb3hOam96TWlCUVJGUWdNakF4TTM0d0xqSXpNVGt3TXpNeGZnJmNyZWF0ZV90aW1lPTEzNzUwOTY2NDYmbm9uY2U9MC44MjM1NjI5MDY2MTA3ODcxJmV4cGlyZV90aW1lPTEzNzUxODMwMjUmY29ubmVjdGlvbl9kYXRhPQ

Comment: Can you post the actual `sessionId` and `token` you used? Don't worry, this won't expose any secure information, all clients get passed that information to connect. It sounds like the `token` doesn't start with `T1==` which all valid tokens do.

Comment: Hey @Ankur I just edit the question to include the session id I used and the Token I used. The token I used had T1.

Answer (score 0):

A valid token will *start* with `T1==`, the token you've shown does not. Can you go back to the Dashboard, create a new token for that session, paste the entire string into your application code, and try again?

Comment: So T1 should be included in the token string ? T1==cGFydG5lcl9pZD0zNjA3NDkwMiZzZGtfdmVyc2lvbj10YnJ1YnktdGJyYi12MC45MS4yMDExLTAyLTE3JnNpZz01MDRiN2NkNDM5ZWJkYWU3YTIxYzA1MDgwNTYxYmI5ZmQ0Y2EwNGIzOnJvbGU9cHVibGlzaGVyJnNlc3Npb25faWQ9Ml9NWDR6TmpBM05Ea3dNbjR4TWpjdU1DNHdMakYtVFc5dUlFcDFiQ0F5T1NBd05EbzFNVG8xTmlCUVJGUWdNakF4TTM0d0xqazJNRFV6TWpWLSZjcmVhdGVfdGltZT0xMzc1MDk4NzE4Jm5vbmNlPTAuNTY4NzI1NjM0MjM3Njg1JmV4cGlyZV90aW1lPTEzNzUxODUwOTcmY29ubmVjdGlvbl9kYXRhPQ==

Comment: would you mind marking this question as answered if that worked our for you?